# 3rd party OAuth integration with Java

Tags: magento2, rest-api, oauth, integration

I'm following the documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1//get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html and I'm a little stuck.

Basically I want to make REST calls from my backend to the Shop to get all products in the shop for example.

Under "Activate an integration" it states, that after activate the Integration it will send a HTTPS POST call with the specific attributes to the callback URL. But on my backend a POST never happens.

Shouldn't I get at least the parameters from the POST call or do I have to implement the other steps too before something happens?

Could someone check out my code/picture and point out some mistakes?

This is the Java Part (I tried RequestParam and RequestAttribute too)

```
@PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
public void authenticate(@RequestHeader("store_base_url") String store_base_url,
                         @RequestHeader("oauth_verifier") String oauth_verifier,
                         @RequestHeader("oauth_consumer_key") String oauth_consumer_key,
                         @RequestHeader("oauth_consumer_key_secret") String oauth_consumer_key_secret) {
    logger.info("Calling MagentoShop.authenticate({} {} {} {})", store_base_url, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_verifier, oauth_consumer_key_secret);
}
```

These are my integration settings

[image: Magento 2 Integration Window]

Much appreciated

Thomas